# Create a "contact us" form in Netsuite

Tags: forms, netsuite

I know that it is possible to create a form that a customer can submit questions to in Netsuite, but I cannot, for the life of me, figure out the best way to do that.

I am looking to make a form on a landing page that collects first and last name, email, a text area for a description of a problem and a way to upload 1-4 images. I would like that information to send to an email address.

We currently have a form on our website powered through a third party that isn't responsive, looks bad and loads extremely slowly.

On another page of our website we have a working form that looks great, but no one knows who built it or how we got it.

I tried creating one myself using basic HTML and a php page, but it simply won't work in Netsuite. As far as I can tell the code is correct, but this method is not testable locally.

SO any ideas on the best way to create a form as I described before within Netsuite.

Comment: https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N976289.html

Comment: I have looked at that one. Do you know if there is a way for it to send the form data in an email? I tested one and it sent me some basic information and then directed me to a Lead in Netsuite and now I can't find the content that was submitted. I'm assuming that I can customize the form that is emailed, but is there a way for it to not create a lead in Netsuite?

Answer (score 0):

Uploading the images is the harder part.

There are various ways to use the external url of an online case form to create whatever form you want.

e.g. https://www.velocitek.com/pages/broken-product-report is a site hosted by Shopify that submits to an online case form in Netsuite.

This could be made to take one item as an upload since case forms can be set up to allow an upload. Don't know if multiple uploads can be easily achieved.

Beyond that you can create your own form handler fairly easily.
The bundle 141427, Fantail Lead Page, aims to replace the online customer forms with a back end that handles AJAX posts. I've used this with Unbounce forms as well as simple html forms. The source could be extended to allow file attachments.